# SSH without password doesn't work with user postgres

Tags: ssh, postgresql, authorized-keys

I've tried manually adding the pub key to authorized_keys and authorized_keys2. I've also double checked the permissions on .ssh (700) and authorized_keys (644). I can login without password on the same machine using another user (server user).

Here's the output from ssh -vvv:

```
ssh postgres@java7 -vvv
OpenSSH_4.3p2, OpenSSL 0.9.8b 04 May 2006
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to java7 [192.168.120.28] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/informix/.ssh/identity type -1
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /home/informix/.ssh/id_rsa.
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug1: identity file /home/informix/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/informix/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: loaded 3 keys
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.3
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_init: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_init: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 118/256
debug2: bits set: 497/1024
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /home/informix/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match line 86
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /home/informix/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match line 82
debug1: Host 'java7' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/informix/.ssh/known_hosts:86
debug2: bits set: 513/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/informix/.ssh/id_rsa (0x555560bb41c0)
debug2: key: /home/informix/.ssh/identity ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/informix/.ssh/id_rsa (0x555560bae620)
debug2: key: /home/informix/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-with-mic
debug3: remaining preferred: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug3: Trying to reverse map address 192.168.120.28.
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Unknown code krb5 195

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Unknown code krb5 195

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Unknown code krb5 195

debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/informix/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/informix/.ssh/identity
debug3: no such identity: /home/informix/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /home/informix/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/informix/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/informix/.ssh/id_dsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
postgres@java7's password:
```

**Edit:**

```
This is an excerpt of what the ssh server on a different port says:
debug1: PAM: initializing for "postgres"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to "192.168.120.97"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"
debug1: userauth-request for user postgres service ssh-connection method publickey
debug1: attempt 1 failures 0
debug1: test whether pkalg/pkblob are acceptable
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 26/26 (e=0/0)
debug1: trying public key file /var/lib/pgsql/.ssh/authorized_keys
debug1: fd 4 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: matching key found: file /var/lib/pgsql/.ssh/authorized_keys, line 4
Found matching RSA key: f5:79:bb:f0:df:57:a3:ee:83:cc:33:a5:1b:b2:5d:ee
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Postponed publickey for postgres from 192.168.120.97 port 45341 ssh2
debug1: userauth-request for user postgres service ssh-connection method publickey
debug1: attempt 2 failures 0
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 26/26 (e=0/0)
debug1: trying public key file /var/lib/pgsql/.ssh/authorized_keys
debug1: fd 4 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: matching key found: file /var/lib/pgsql/.ssh/authorized_keys, line 4
Found matching RSA key: f5:79:bb:f0:df:57:a3:ee:83:cc:33:a5:1b:b2:5d:ee
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: do_pam_account: called
Accepted publickey for postgres from 192.168.120.97 port 45341 ssh2
debug1: monitor_child_preauth: postgres has been authenticated by privileged process
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 26/26 (e=0/0)
debug1: ssh_gssapi_storecreds: Not a GSSAPI mechanism
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
debug1: SELinux support enabled
debug1: PAM: establishing credentials
PAM: pam_open_session(): Authentication failure
User child is on pid 10198
debug1: PAM: establishing credentials
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 26/26
debug1: Entering interactive session for SSH2.
debug1: server_init_dispatch_20
debug1: server_input_channel_open: ctype session rchan 0 win 65536 max 16384
debug1: input_session_request
debug1: channel 0: new [server-session]
debug1: session_new: session 0
debug1: session_open: channel 0
debug1: session_open: session 0: link with channel 0
debug1: server_input_channel_open: confirm session
debug1: server_input_channel_req: channel 0 request pty-req reply 0
debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req pty-req
debug1: Allocating pty.
debug1: session_new: session 0
ssh_selinux_setup_pty: security_compute_relabel: Invalid argument
debug1: session_pty_req: session 0 alloc /dev/pts/5
debug1: server_input_channel_req: channel 0 request env reply 0
debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req env
debug1: server_input_channel_req: channel 0 request shell reply 0
debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req shell
debug1: Setting controlling tty using TIOCSCTTY.
debug1: Received SIGCHLD.
debug1: session_by_pid: pid 10199
debug1: session_exit_message: session 0 channel 0 pid 10199
debug1: session_exit_message: release channel 0
debug1: session_by_tty: session 0 tty /dev/pts/5
debug1: session_pty_cleanup: session 0 release /dev/pts/5
debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
debug1: session_close_by_channel: channel 0 child 0
debug1: session_close: session 0 pid 0
debug1: channel 0: free: server-session, nchannels 1
Connection closed by 192.168.120.97
debug1: do_cleanup
Transferred: sent 2296, received 2416 bytes
Closing connection to 192.168.120.97 port 45341
debug1: PAM: cleanup
debug1: PAM: deleting credentials
```

**/var/log/secure.log when running another ssh server**:

```
Apr  4 16:52:31 java7 sshd[10774]: pam_selinux(sshd:session): conversation failed
Apr  4 16:52:31 java7 sshd[10774]: pam_selinux(sshd:session): No response to query: Would you like to enter a security context? [N]
Apr  4 16:52:31 java7 sshd[10774]: pam_selinux(sshd:session): Unable to get valid context for postgres
Apr  4 16:52:31 java7 sshd[10774]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user postgres by (uid=0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the best thing to do in these circumstances is to run the SSH daemon in debug mode.  If you have access as root on the machine you can run:

```
# /usr/sbin/sshd -d -p 2222
```

and then you can use:

```
# ssh -p 2222 postgres@java7
```

and see what reason the server gives for rejecting the key.

Comment: I've added the output from the ssh server. I believe the problem is in "PAM: pam_open_session(): Authentication failure", but I'm still looking for a solution.

Comment: Ok, so now you need to go look in /etc/pam.d/sshd and check through each of the 'required' entries and also follow to any @included files, to see if there are any criteria that would fail for the postgres account.  You could also check in /var/log/auth.log for any clues relating to pam.

Comment: Added excerpt from /var/log/secure (I don't have auth.log).

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but if I can login by writing the password, there shouldn't be any pam problems. Right?

Comment: It depends on what is 'sufficient' to log in with your configuration.  There's different parts to pam - authentication is just one, and will be skipped if the key works, which it does.  The account section of pam is probably where it is falling down, which may succeed if it has done the authentication part first, as with entering the password.

Comment: OK, even though I couldn't find the solution for my problem (I don't want to fall on the deep hole that PAM signifies for me), you helped me get WHY it was failing, so I'll mark this answer as correct.

Answer (score 2):

You can turn on debug logs on your existing ssh server. In file /etc/ssh/sshd_config change 

`LogLevel DEBUG3`

if the reason for unsuccessful login is
`Could not open authorized keys '/var/lib/pgsql/.ssh/authorized_keys': Permission denied` and access rights to authorized_keys seems ok, then this command will help

`restorecon -FRvv /var/lib/pgsql/.ssh/`

[explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20688844/sshd-gives-error-could-not-open-authorized-keys-although-permissions-seem-corre)

Answer (score 1):

Is 'postgres' the user generated by installing the PostreSQL server? If so, most auto-generated users can't be "logged in"; they exist solely for the purposes of the daemon(s) that need file permissions.

Comment: Yes it is, and it can be logged in. When the key auth fails, it prompts for a password. When I enter the password, the user gets logged in as any user.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.5 SELinux feature preventing sshd from reading $HOME/.ssh is to use restorecon, see my answser here https://superuser.com/a/764020/213743.

Answer (score -1):

make sure that your selinux is set correctly.

i changed the selinux to **permissive** and it works or you have to add .ssh to selinux roles.