# Redhat Linux password fail on ssh

Tags: ssh, redhat-enterprise-linux

I am trying to ssh into my linux machine from my mac. If I am physically at the machine I can log in with my password just fine, but if I am sshing it refuses. I am getting: Permission denies (publickey,keyboard-interactive) 
I have previously been able to ssh in (last time was probably about a month ago) but all of a sudden I can't access it any more. 
I thought that it might be caused by some changes that I recently made to system-auth, but I restored everything to what I believe was the original format:

```
#%PAM-1.0
# This file is auto-generated.
# User changes will be destroyed the next time authconfig is run.
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        sufficient    pam_fprintd.so
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 500 quiet
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_unix.so
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 500 quiet
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_cracklib.so try_first_pass retry=3
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so md5 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
```

But I still could not ssh in. I tried removing my password all together and that didn't seem to help either. It still asks and even entering an empty string (nothing) it still fails me out.

I checked the  sshd_config, at the suggestion of an answer below, and that does not seem to be the issue.

```
PermitEmptyPasswords yes
PasswordAuthentication yes
UsePAM yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile      /home/%u/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

I haven't actually looked into this file, before it was suggested, so I imagine most of it is probably still system defaults.

And I am still shut out through ssh.

Any advice?

Comment: you trying to login as root or another user?

Comment: Logging in does not work as root or any other user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out there was a problem with a shifting ip address. I double checked `ifconfig` and realized that the ip was different than previously. I gave it a static ip and the problem has not resurfaced.

Answer (score 4):

If you're running Red Hat with Security Enchanced Linux enabled (SELinux), then you might be having a problem because SELinux is preventing sshd from reading $HOME/.ssh.  To make SELinux happy, you have to do

```
root@sshd-server# restorecon -Rv ~/.ssh
```

To see if you're running with SELinux enabled use sestatus.  Here's what it looks like if SELinux is enabled.

```
root@sshd-server# sestatus
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /selinux
Current mode:                   enforcing
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy version:                 24
Policy from config file:        targeted
```

Note that you may also have to change the security context of the .ssh file.  Use the `-Z` switch to the `ls` command like:

```
ls -laZ ~/.ssh
```

Which may report a security context like `system_u:object_r:default_t:s0`.
Then use the `chcon` command like:

```
chcon -R -v system_u:object_r:usr_t:s0 ~/.ssh/
```

Thanks to Massimo Ronca's post titled "Fixing SELinux and passwordless SSH authentication"[1] for the `chcon` tip.

1- https://massimoronca.it/2017/03/14/fixing-selinux-and-passwordless-ssh-authentication.html

Comment: saved my life...  I tried to `setenforce 0` and also tried to view errors in `/var/log/secure` and nothing helped

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your `ssh` is configured to not allow password login (which is an encouraged security approach).  There are two solutions: change the setting or setup keys on your mac machine.

**To change the setting**

- Edit your `sshd_config` file (`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`):
- Find entry `PasswordAuthentication` and make sure it's set to `yes` (will likely be `no` or commented out)
- Restart sshd: `service sshd restart`
- You can now connect with username/password

**To setup keys**

- [Create a key pair on the machine you're connecting from](https://drupal.org/node/1070130)
- [Store the public aspect on the remote server](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Network_Satellite/5.0/html/Reference_Guide/s2-mon-rhnmd-ssh.html) (under `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`)
- Configure `ssh` to connect using the key rather than a password
- There's a good overview of this here: [MacNugget/Using SSH Public Key Authentication](http://macnugget.org/projects/publickeys/)

**NOTE:**

The easiest way to push your public key (*setup keys* option) is through `ssh`, so you may actually want to turn `PasswordAuthentication` on setup keys and then turn it off again once your key is setup.

Comment: I have PasswordAuthentication set to yes and it isn't commented out. I am not sure I understand what you mean in the setup keys section. Can you be more specific? Thanks

Comment: Going to need to know more settings from your `sshd` there are all sorts of other settings in there that can prevent users or hosts from using the protocol.  Is this a new problem or has it never worked? [you mention changes]

Comment: I just noticed it today, previously I have been able to succeed at sshing in, but the last time I tried was probably a month ago. Which was before I made changes to the system-auth file.

Comment: @Stephopolis do you have a `/etc/sshd/sshd.allow` file?  Are there users within it?  What's the result of `tail -f /var/log/auth.log` right after an ssh attempt?

Comment: In addition to setting `PasswordAuthentication` to `yes` I also had to set `ChallengeResponseAuthentication` to `yes`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know what's going on, try to setup another SSH daemon on another port with debug mode :

```
server# /usr/sbin/sshd -p 2222 -d
```

Then, try to connect to your ssh server:

```
client$ ssh server -p 2222
```

If you don't have any relevant output in the server debug, try adding more "-d" up to 3 to increase debug level.

Good luck